# Solr index directory of files add file permissions from database

Tags: wordpress, solr

I'm using Solr to index a directory of pdf and word files. I want Solr to search these files but only return results based off a logged in user's permissions. Is it possible to index a directory of files as well as query a database containing the file permissions and add the data to the index as a xml entity and perform a filtered query on those results?

I am using WordPress as the CMS system with a file management plugin called Filebase. Filebase syncs with a directory to upload documents to the site. I have Solr configured to index the filebase directory containing the documents. Filebase has permissions that I set on each file.

My thought is if I can store the file's minimum user level position integer in the index I can then perform a filtered query to only display results with a user level of 'x'.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you are on Solr 4+, you can push a Partial Update to Solr index.

**SCHEMA**

For partial update, **all fields in your schema.xml need to be stored**.

This is how your fields section should look like in schema.xml:

```
<fields>
  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
  <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="body" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="permission" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" />
</fields>
```

---

**INDEXING:**

You can first index all documents(directory of pdf and word) to your index.

Then you can send a partial update to the permission field for a particular id.

When you send partial update, what actually happens in background is:

- Solr will go and fetch values for all other fields for that document, such as title, description, body
- Delete old document
- Push new updated document to Solr index, with all existing fields as well as new permission field

Suppose you want to set permission=5 for document with id=document_1, your query should look like:

```
localhost:8080/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"document_1","permission":{"set":5}}]
```

Here is a good documentation on partial updates: http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

Comment: That's excellent, thank you. I am attempting to implement this using php and will need to somehow hook it into the other plugin when new files are added that this script will automatically run on that new file. Will I need to execute this query using curl?

Comment: Here is a good discussion on updating index using Solr PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620088/how-do-i-update-a-document-in-solr-php

Comment: @raupie am glad my answer helped you. You might want to check following URL on accepting answers, it informs others that your issue is resolved. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: I've been through that forum several times andthe link http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/. There isn't any php implementations or example scripts. I don't want to use command line to update 500+ documents. I did use the addDocument function but it erased everything and added just the new updated field.

Comment: you can use file_get_contents along with a for loop. iterate over all docs you want to update, and push each of them one by one.
eg:
for_each{
file_get_contents("localhost:8080/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"$ID","permission":{"set":$permission}}]);
}