# solr update specific fields rather than entire document

Tags: solr

Does solr allow updating specific field rather than indexing entire document.

I know solr 1.4 doesn't.

Has this been implemented in newer versions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update specific field on SOLR index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032813/update-specific-field-on-solr-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Solr doesn't allow updating a specific field.
You would need to update the document again with all the existing values and the changed values.
The Update basically is delete and add of the document.

**Update**

Solr does Allow Partial Updates with 4.0 @ http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

Comment: Now there is "Updating Parts of Documents" feature: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html

Answer (score 27):

Not the correct answer anymore. SOLR 4.0 supports the partial updates you are talking about. See http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

Comment: that right, I did it like you said, but I have other questions, if my schema.xml file not defined the primary key, I want to update documents by conditions, I throw a exception, it can not update fields by conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Atomic updates are possible in solr. Please refer https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON#Solr_4.0_Example