# Update specific field on SOLR index without storing other fields?

Tags: solr, lucene, lucene.net

Is it possible in SOLR to update specific field on indexed document without storing other fields ?
     I am using Apache Lucene in which update field internally delete original document and index all fields from document, which leads to store all fields values while indexing, and Storing all fields values degraded the indexing performance.
     I got [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365713/solr-update-specific-fields-rather-than-entire-document) which says it is possible to update documents without storing the other fields values.

Comment: there's some support for "external file fields" which might help http://www.openjems.com/solr-external-file-fields/