# SolrJ: Ignore fields on update

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am searching for a way to update Solr documents via SolrJ client only partially. Documentation about SolrInputDocument object here https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_3_0/solr-solrj/index.html
didn't show any obvious possibility to do this.

There exist partial updates in Solr, but I could not find a way to do this via SolrJ - am I missing something?

The "solution" to read the document first and re-use values of existing fields + change the desired ones seems not like a real performant solution to me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [solrj api for partial document update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183798/solrj-api-for-partial-document-update)

Answer (score -1):

yes there is a way to update the solr document partially .
Here is the link to tutorial which describes this feature 
[link to document](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/)

I think your question can be duplicate of this .

[solr update specific fields rather than entire document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365713/solr-update-specific-fields-rather-than-entire-document)

Comment: OP asks if it is possible to trigger that mechanism via the SolrJ API. Appears that he know that partial works.